# How to set real names for forkJoin responses?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

When I subscribe on forkJoin response I get array of responses by index depending number of joined requests:

```
forkResponse[0]
forkResponse[1]

this.loadComponentData().subscribe((forkResponse) => {
 console.log(forkResponse); 
});
```

Is it possible to set real names instead indexes? I mean like this:

```
forkResponse['numbers']
forkResponse['dogs']
```

Also what I will give if one request is falled? Will be this `forkResponse['dogs']` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing the observable into the array, we can assign using custom index value.

**In Service**

```
loadComponentData(){
   const observableArr = [];
   observableArr['numbers'] = this.getDataById(1);
   observableArr['dogs'] = this.getDataById(2);
  return Observable.forkJoin(observableArr);
}

getDataById() : Observable<any> {
   return of(true);
}
```

Comment: Also what I will give if one request is falled? Will be this forkResponse['dogs'] is null?

Comment: Thank you, I accept your answer, also say me please how to handle errors?

Comment: So I mean I dont like this way `if (forkResponse['numbers'] !== null) {// do }`

Comment: If you don't like individual Cond. You can do forEach and based on key. you can validate whether value is null.

Comment: Can you demonstrate example?

Comment: const errorexisit = false; for (var key in forkResponse){ if(!forkResponse[key]) {errorexisit = true;}};